# Wireless Mesh network with contiki OS

Tags: sensors, wireless, contiki, cooja

I am working on a project called sensorhub. In that, sensors needs to communicate with each other in a  mesh network and need to send the data to the border router.

I found that contiki os can do the mesh network work.but i didn't know how to get started with it.
My question is,

1. Is there any possibility that cc26xx can be done with cooja simulator ?
2. If answer to the first question is No. what kind of things I need to follow to make the mesh network work with cc26xx/cc13xx?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You can use `msp430` based platforms, such as `sky` or `z1` in Cooja.
2. Contiki uses RPL for IPv6 multihop routing in order to build a single-parent routing tree on top of the mesh. The mesh network is a sort of service provided by the system, you don't need to do anything special to enable it. See `contiki/examples/ipv6/` for some examples on how to send packets between nodes. These examples work in both star and mesh network topologies, as long as there's a RPL root node somewhere in the network.

Comment: if i want to implement mesh network feature in cc1350, what sholud be the procedure i need to follow in cooja. please help me in steps, and thank you for your quick response.

Comment: You can't implement cc1350 network in Cooja - please read my answer!

Comment: Implementation of cc1350 in cooja cannot be done - that is ok. But, I am asking how can I implement a mesh network design on CC1350 boards apart from contiki os technique.

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you try to follow my suggestions at all? If there's a specific problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: I tried sky motes - that is working fine with cooja, but I just want to know that , How can I implement same sky mote technique on CC1350 launchpad. I think the code of skymote doesnot work on CC1350. I struck at this point bro! please suggest me some path to move further.